# Slicing 2 dimensional array of strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, slice

I have a string array where I need to display from 2nd item onwards. But within each item I need to further display from 2nd item. Say

I have an array

```
function myFunction() {
    var fruits = ["BBanana", "BOrange", "TLemon", "TApple", "YMango"];
    var citrus = fruits.slice(1).join("<br/>"); //skip first item
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = citrus;
}
```

The expected output is

```
Orange
Lemon
Apple
Mango
```

Instead

```
BOrange
TLemon
TApple
YMango
```

How do i achieve using improved performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you slice off the 1st item, use [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create a list of item without the 1st letter using [String#substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring), then join:

Map and then join:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var fruits = ["BBanana", "BOrange", "TLemon", "TApple", "YMango"];
  var citrus = fruits.slice(1)
    .map(function(str) {
      return str.substring(1);
    })
    .join("<br/>");
  demo.innerHTML = citrus;
}

myFunction();
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var fruits = ["BBanana", "BOrange", "TLemon", "TApple", "YMango"];
    for(var i = 1; i < fruits.length; i++){
console.log(fruits[i].slice(1));
};
```

Comment: Whether this is efficient?

Answer (score 1):

You can use reduce function, it will be less code than in other cases

```
function myFunction() {
    const fruits = ["BBanana", "BOrange", "TLemon", "TApple", "YMango"];   
    const temp = fruits.slice(1).reduce( (ac, item) => ac + `${item.slice(1)}<br/>`, '')

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = temp;
}
```